# gitflow: how to make local develop follow remote develop — again?

Tags: git, git-flow, git-merge-conflict

We use gitflow with pull requests so in theory the local and remote develop should always be identical. But in praxis there are merge conflicts.

I don't want to merge those conflicts as I would not be allowed to push them anyway.

Is there a way to just force the local develop branch to be the same as the remote develop branch?

Comment: Did you actually mean "convicts"?

Comment: *conflicts

(useless extra text which adds nothing to the comment but makes the comment of a needed minimum size)

Comment: Much more coherent *and* much less funny. Thanks. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to discard the changes on the local develop branch 
you can do the following

```
git reset --hard origin/master
git pull origin master
```

or delete the branch and pull it again

```
git checkout master
git branch -D develop
git checkout develop
```

If you want to force your changes to the remote develop

```
git push -f
```

This will Force push to the remote branch so be careful as all the remote changes will be deleted.

If you want to apply your local changes on the remote that has been modified you can do the following

```
git pull --rebase #This will bring your local commit on top of the remote. Then you can resolve the conflicts and push to the remote
```

Comment: The 2nd option should that `git checkout master` not be a `git checkout "remotes/origin/develop` ?

Comment: Since I want to delete develop, I have to be in any other branch than develop. So I go to master. you can go to any other branch you want and delete develop

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @dionysis-nt answer I came up with the following slight variation of this 2nd suggestion which worked:

```
git checkout "remotes/origin/develop"
git branch --delete --force "develop"
git checkout -b "develop"
```